# Are mathematical operations different for different data types?

Tags: java, types, operator-precedence

Why is it that in the first line sevenTwelfths will evaluate to the expected answer (0.5833), but threeTwentySixths will evaluate to zero? I assumed that since the data type is a double, the operation of dividing 3 by 26 would be a decimal, but it appears as if it does the operation as an integer operation and then coverts that answer to a double and stores it in threeTwentySixths.

```
    double sevenTwelfths = ((double) 7 / 12);
    double threeTwentySixths = 3 / 26;
```

Comment: Yes they are different.  int / int -> int.  double / int -> double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double sevenTwelfths = ((double) 7 / 12);

In First line this called typecasting meaning you are converting your answer in double for example

int sevenTwelfths=((int)7/12));
this mean after dividing 7/12 whatever is the anser convert into int or Type cast into int